# auto complete names in a cell from a hidden row

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a spreadsheet with a vertical list of about 150 names hidden, Is there a way to auto complete the names when i start to type them in another cell? I don't see that this can be done. Thanks for any help.

Comment: No. The only way for autocomplete to work is in the current column with current, contiguous, data. Autocomplete doesn't work across the whole worksheet.

Comment: thanks, that's what i'm finding out. Appreciate the reply

Answer (score 0):

I was able to drag and/or copy to whatever cell I needed to. If you know where the names are hidden (by looking in the function (fx) box) then you can drag the list. Plus you can unhide the list if needed.